# contour lines and turning points of $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \vec{x} \mapsto |\vec{a}-\vec{x}|$

Tags: real-analysis

Given the vector $\vec{a}=(2,2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we define

$f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \vec{x} \mapsto |\vec{a}-\vec{x}|$

(i) Determine the contour lines of $f$ to the values $-1,0,1,2$

(ii) Be $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x^2+y^2\leq 4, x<0\}$ Has $f$ a minimum and a maximum in $A$?

My problem is, that i can't see, what this function actually looks like...
Despite this, i tried to calculate some contour lines:

(i) $f(x,y)=c, c \in \mathbb{R}$

$\sqrt{(2-x)^2+(2-y)^2}=-1 \rightarrow y=2-\sqrt{3-4x+x^2}$

$\sqrt{(2-x)^2+(2-y)^2}=0 \rightarrow y=2-\sqrt{-4+4x-x^2}$

$\sqrt{(2-x)^2+(2-y)^2}=1 \rightarrow y=2-\sqrt{3-4x+x^2}$

$\sqrt{(2-x)^2+(2-y)^2}=2 \rightarrow y= 2- \sqrt{4x-x^2}$

Is my solution for subtask (i) correct?

So what this function descriptively does, is that it measures distance of each vecotr in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the point $(2,2)$. Is this correct?

(ii) $f$ has no turning points, since $A$ is not compact.

Comment: [pic](http://i.imgur.com/oxsQJkq.png).